# What is the name of global variable in bigcommerce which is used to get the email of the Store Profile?

Tags: bigcommerce

I already searched on Developer Portal of the Bigcommerce but I not found.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/global_variables

Can you help me?

Comment: Checking in to see if that worked out for you?

Answer (score 0):

This Global Variable shows the email address under the Store Settings

%%GLOBAL_AdminEmail%%